# How use Face ID with double click like App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, face-id

I'm making an app with sensitive info for user.
I implemented face id and touch id, but the face id is very fast and I want to make sure the user did not push the button in my app by mistake.

For this I wanted to implement the double tap on the side button as it happens in the app store.

I read Apple's documentation on the face id, LocalAuthentication, and LAContext but did not find anything about it? Is there any way to get this diclaimer or to detect the double tap on the side button?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can’t catch a double press of the side button. You need to make your own custom UI that confirms after successfully using Face ID, but before taking the action.

If you want something simple and intuitive, use `UIAlertController` with the action sheet style.